# More than four parameters in UIApplicationMain method

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to implement two reset timers in  my application, So i user third party Code to implement. But to use those timer i need to accommodate parameters in the Main.M file like below

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv,@"ELCUIApplication",@"MQTimeOut", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

My problem it show  an error  if i set more than four parameter.

Comment: Nah - you've gone wrong here somewhere.  I don't understand why you would change this call at all.

Comment: because to use those timer in my application.

Comment: I see you are using [this code](https://github.com/marqeta/mqtimeout) that implements the timing functionality using a `UIApplication` subclass.  What you need to do is pull the functionality from that code while maintaining your existing application class.  You don't want to replace your application class with the one they show.  I haven't looked at the code in detail, but implementing the functionality as a `UIApplication`-subclass is very difficult to integrate into other projects.  I would therefore suspect the code is complete rubbish :)  Find something else.

Comment: okay , Thanks for the info